# How to make websites in iframe act as in specific width

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do you make something like [this](https://material.io/resizer/) which is iframe and (for example) acts as 1920px width in 1024px container. I need to make users check the page in various display widths on the page rather than using developer tools. Forgive me for my bad English and bad writing skill. I really appreciate your effort and time.

Comment: put it in an iframe and use css to resize the iframe... try if before asking for help

Comment: I searched and only thing i found was that but if you make the width of iframe greater than container it will overflow and doesn't scale also the media queries won't work properly i think. I need to make something really close to that resizer i linked. Thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: also tried : ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your iframe to the actual target width, e.g. say, 1920px, then play with CSS transform:scale:

```
iframe {
    transform: scale(.3);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

Don't forget your vendor prefixes.